# Multiple hide show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to do this all day. At the end i managed to get it working. I know it is not the best way to do.

Can someone please show me a better way. I need 12 altogether. It does not need to be check box either. It can be just a text. I got the idea from com/2006/12/14/using-jquery-to-show-hide-form-elements-based-on-a-checkbox-selection/

I managed to upload it on http://utilitybase.com/paste/wmq

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra").hide("fast");
        }
      });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra1").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme1").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme1").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra1").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra1").hide("fast");
        }
      });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra2").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme2").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme2").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra2").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra2").hide("fast");
        }
      });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra3").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme3").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme3").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra3").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra3").hide("fast");
        }
      });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra4").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme4").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme4").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra4").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra4").hide("fast");
        }
      });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 800px;">
        <form>

            <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
            <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
            <input id="checkme" type="checkbox" />

            <div id="extra">
            <input type="text" name="input" maxlength="30" />
            <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
            <input id="checkme1" type="checkbox" />

            <div id="extra1">
            <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
            <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
            <input id="checkme2" type="checkbox" />

            <div id="extra2">
            <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
            <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
            <input id="checkme3" type="checkbox" />

            <div id="extra3">
            <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
            <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
            <input id="checkme4" type="checkbox" /> 

            <div id="extra4">
            <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your formatting evokes eye cancer... try http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I know... It is on http://utilitybase.com/paste/wmq now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you might play around with

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var prototype = $('.prototype').clone();

      $('.prototype > input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var clone = prototype.clone();
          clone.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
          $(this).parent('.prototype').append(clone);
        } else {
          $(this).parent('.prototype').find('.prototype:last').remove();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="prototype">
      <input type="text" name="" maxlength="30" />
      <label for="checkbox"> Check to enter another email address:</label>
      <input id="checkme" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**: This add's a new input/label/checkbox prototype inside the current one or removes it's children on the other hand. You could add ids to the fields as well.

Comment: it works nearly perfect. if you click 4-5 times and try to unclick it and click it again it does not close 1 by one. it closes 3-4 of them and if you click the top one it opens 1 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

thats nice .

Did  you try .each or .live

http://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Or select it and hit 'ctrl + K'.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Looking at your code on UtilityBase. Maybe try using the `.siblings()` jquery function. Then for the click of the checkbox you can do a `$(this).siblings('div').hide()/show();`

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me

```
$("div[id^='extra']").click(function(){
  $div = $(this);
  divID = $div.attr("id").substring(5);

//Hide div w/id extra
       $div.css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#checkme"+divID).click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#checkme"+divID).is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $div.show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $div.hide("fast");
        }

});
```

This should keep you from having to write the same thing multiple timesdiv

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
// isolate the first div. You can surely find a better way,
// using classes, containers, etc., but this works for now. 
// Hide all the others.
$('div:has(input):not(:first)').hide();

// For each checkbox, open the next div
$('input:checkbox').click( function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
    $(this).next('div').show('fast');
  } else {
    $(this).next('div').hide('fast');
  }
});
```